# Not getting "Add unimplemented methods" error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng, listener

I am working on Selenium with Java and using Listeners.

I created the class, imported the TestNG, and then added method as;

```
Public class Listener implements ITestListener{
}
```

I got an error at "ITestListner" and then imported "ITestListner(org.testng). After this it was expected that I will get an error for "Listener" but I didn't get any error.

I tried creating with abstract class but still didn't get the error.

```
package com.testng;

import org.testng.ITestListener;

public class Listeners implements ITestListener{

}
```

The expectation is when I move the cursor over "Listeners" I should get "Add unimplemented methods" option.

Comment: Is ITestListener.java file available in the defined package ?

Comment: No, my class name is Listeners, I used ITestListener to implement the Listener methods.

Comment: What are the methods available inside ITestListener class. I assume ITestListener is an interface.

Comment: Yes, its an interface. If I get the "Add unimplemented methods" option, below code will be exposed.

Comment: Post the code for ITestListener.java

Comment: `@Override
 public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

 @Override
 public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 // System.out.println("I successfully executed Listeners Pass code");
 }

 @Override
 public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //screenshot code 
  //response if API is failed
  
  System.out.println("I failed executed Listeners Pass code" +result.getName());

 }`

Comment: This is the code for method, edit your question and add the complete code for ITestListener.java.

Answer (score 12):

Right click(on the Listeners class ) -> go to source-> click on overide/implement methods -> select the check boxes for the ITest listener (make sure all check box inside it should be checked )->click on oK. That's it !!!

Answer (score 2):

As i got to know from the below link - TestNG 7.0.0 uses JDK8 and with it default methods within interfaces. What this means is that every listener would now have a default implementation (which doesn't do anything ) for all methods defined within the interface.

So now you won't see those indications from the IDE. The biggest benefit of default methods in interfaces is that let's say you are implementing an interface that has 10 methods defined in it, you can just implement whatever you need and the rest of the behavior comes via the default methods in the interface.
Reference-
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1964

Comment: I see, by [adding empty default implementations](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/commit/3006219166232fc643bee513c84bb6772277a0d6#diff-8853c664e8e938b88ec7cb0677afac15), the [listener interface became an adapter](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/listeners-vs-adapters). Probably the name was not changed due to compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the class --> select source --> choose override/implement methods --> then pick the methods you'd like to implement.

Answer (score 1):

All methods in ITestListener interface changed to default from 7 version onwards. You can call them with class object where you implemented interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the TestNg version to **6.14.3**.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Best solution is go to the source tab besides the File-Edit options and click the Overide/implement methods and you are set

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Eclipse might not be displaying the "Add unimplemented methods" error on hovering over the class name. However, you can still generate the unimplemented methods by following these steps:

1. Right-click on the class name in the editor.
2. Navigate to "Generate" in the context menu.
3. Select "Override Methods" from the submenu.
4. A dialog will appear listing the methods that can be overridden. Choose the methods you want to override.
5. Click "OK" to generate the selected overridden methods.

This way, you can manually generate the unimplemented methods even if the IDE is not showing the error on hovering over the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Right click(on the Listeners class ) -> go to source-> click on overide/implement methods -> select the check boxes for the ITest listener (make sure all check box inside it should be checked )->click on oK.

[image: step1]
[image: step2]